# Posting incorrect json payload with Ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to do something simple but I'm clearly missing something. I want to post data from a form into a web-service using `json`. Simple right?

I have my HTML

```
    <div id="addDiv">
    <form id="addItemForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="title">Title</label> 
            <input id="title" class="txt" type="text" name="title"/></BR>

            <label for="url">URL</label> 
            <input id="url" class="txt" type="text" name="url"/></BR>

            <label for="author">Author</label> 
            <input id="author" class="txt" type="text" name="author"/>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in my `js` file I do:

```
              JSONdata = JSON.stringify($('#addItemForm').serialize());
          console.log("Form transformed to: " + JSONdata);
```

payload output(JSONdata):

```
Form transformed to: "title=tgtg&url=5rfrf&author=yhyhyyh"
```

My Ajax code just in case:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSONdata,
    contentType : 'application/json',
            ............
```

So the problem I see is that the `json` string is not a valid one like `[{ "title": "tgtg", "url": "5rfrf" .... },{...}]`

Therefore, my service fails.
I've tried with a REST tester and the service has no problems, the problem is when i try to post via `jquery.`

I've also tried with `serializeArray()` but I get a different payload also incorrect:

```
[{"name":"title","value":"tgtg"},{"name":"url","value":"5rfrf"},...]
```

In other words, I can't find a way to create a proper `json` string to send via post.

thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), but the [`serializeArray` method](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). If you need it in an object, you then still can make the `name`-`value` pairs properties of an object:

```
var res = {},
    arr = $('#addItemForm').serializeArray();
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    res[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
```

Comment: thanks man, this works as I expect, I thought there was an easier way. Like a command without the need of looping..but thanks anyway!!